Tag dupe: legal, law, illegal
Unless I'm mistaken, on most SE site they use the legal tag; here we had ~10 posts with that tag, 5 with law and only 1 with illegal.
Hence, I'm removing those two in favour of legal.

Thanks for your efforts, I agree that legal is a much better tag for law-based questions and as such have created synonyms for law and illegal pointing to legal as well as merged the tags. Since you've already retagged the posts the merge did precisely nothing but it never hurts to be thorough ;)
